# Database subclassing design

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Im creating db project and one thing is no so clear for me. Have a look at this:
[image: part of database model]

Now im not sure what's the best way to make physical model. TOOL and RESOURCE doesn't need any other fields than ITEM. Only Recipe needs new column(for). But I have to somehow distinguish recipes from tools and resources. Ok I can create 2 same tables with different names for resources and tools, and one for recipe, but what I do with items then? Create is as view? Then it won't be really subclassing.

Or i just create something like that: Create ITEM table with (id,name,description) and then just RESOURCE with (item_id) thats foreign key and same with tools and add trigger that when I insert into resources it really adds to ITEM and then just adds foreign key in resources? Thats seems like most sensible option, but is it possible?

Comment: Not for building DB. I'am supossed to write in using least ORM possible. I mean I can use ORM for querying, but I still have to built it with pure SQL.

Comment: Will any of child tables will have specific relationship? Example: table Tool would have relationship to some other table that Recipe and Resource would not.

Comment: @LIUFA nope all relationships have been shown on image.

Comment: I would go with JoelBrown's solution then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic "It depends" answer. The answer really depends on the potential relationships and whether an item can belong to more than one type.

If there will be relations that all items can be in, then a single items table would be preferable since you can have a single foreign key column in your relation table. If there will be relations that only specific types of item can have,
then you will need to use [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html), so as you have said for Tool for example, you would
have another table called `Tools`, with a single primary key column `ItemID` that references Item. This way you can create foreign keys to `Tools.ItemID` limiting relationships
to a certain type of item. If an item can belong to more than one type then you should almost certainly use Class Table Inheritance.

If you don't need to limit relations, and an item can only belong to one type, then you can just identify item types by having an `ItemType` column in the Items table, no need to use table inheritance at all.

If there won't be relations that more than one itemtype can be in, and there will be relations that only one can appear in then it may be simpler, and less maintenance to use 3 tables, and use a view to combine them, it should still provide all the functionality needed.

In summary, Inheritance will require more tables, and more management, but is more flexible, so it depends.

Answer (score 2):

Based on just the requirements that you've presented, I would suggest physically implementing only a single table (item) with a **partitioning attribute**, e.g. `item_type`.  You can use check constraints to ensure that the extra columns that apply only to recipes are null for other item types and not-null for recipes.

If it makes sense for your application, for example if you have to coerce an ORM into working the way you want it to, then you could create views for the three different subtypes.

If your needs expand to include many distinct predicates (columns) per sub-type, then you might want to consider splitting out the distinct predicates into sub-type tables, leaving the common predicates at the super-type level.  You would still want to have a partitioning attribute in either case.  There is no hard and fast rule for when to implement physical sub-types.  It is a matter of trade-offs and to some extent, personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

The question of designing subclasses (also known as "IS-A" relationships) comes up from time to time in here.  You can get a general discussion of the question by visiting the [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) tag and reading the info tab.  Also, the Fowler reference given by GarethD will give you an excellent treatment of the subject.